database returns error 400 whenever I want to insert data into it
so this is my code, whenever I gonna insert data into my database it returns error 400 I don't know the reason, I did other crud operations and it was fine.
import React from 'react';
import { Formik, Form, Field} from 'formik';
import axios from 'axios';

const AddProduct = () => {

    const handleFileChange = (event, setFieldValue) => {
        const file = event.currentTarget.files[0];
        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onloadend = () => {
            const blob = new Blob([reader.result], {
                type: file.type
            });
            setFieldValue('pic', blob);
        };
        reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
    };

  return (
    <Formik
        initialValues={{
            name: '',
            desc: '', // You can use a date picker library for this field
            pic: '',
            price: '',
        }}
        onSubmit={(values) => {

            const formData = new FormData();

            formData.append('name', values.name);
            formData.append('category', values.category);
            formData.append('desc', values.desc);
            formData.append('price', parseFloat(values.price).toFixed(2));
            formData.append('pic', values.pic);

            axios.post('http://localhost:3002/products/', formData)
                .then(response => {
                    console.log(response.data);
                })
        }}
        >
        {({ isSubmitting, setFieldValue }) => (
            <Form className='addproduct-form-container'>
                <Field type="text" name="name" placeholder="عنوان محصول" className='addproduct-product-name'/>
                <Field type="text" name="desc" placeholder="توضیحات" className='addproduct-product-desc'/>
                <input type="file" name="pic" placeholder="تصویر محصول" className='addproduct-product-pic' onChange={ (event) => handleFileChange(event, setFieldValue) }/>
                <Field type="number" name="price" placeholder="قیمت محصول (تومان)" className='addproduct-product-price' />
                <button type="submit" disabled={isSubmitting}  className='addproduct-product-submit'>انجام</button>
            </Form>
        )}
    </Formik>
  )
}

export default AddProduct

when I log the form data it returns values and values are right but when I submit it returns error 400
it seems that the reason is notNull violation but as I said I logged the values before sending them.
routes/products.js:
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const Products = require('../models/Product');

//Create a Product
router.post('/', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const product = await Products.create(req.body);
        res.status(201).json(product);
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(400).json({ error: error.message });
    }
});

// Read All Products 
router.get('/', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const products = await Products.findAll();

        const imageBlobs = products.map(image => ({
            id: image.id,
            title: image.name,
            description: image.description,
            category: image.category,
            price: image.price,
            image: image.image.toString('base64')
        }));


        res.status(200).json(imageBlobs);

    } catch (error) {
        res.status(400).json({ error: error.message });
    }
});

router.get('/:id', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const product = await Products.findByPk(req.params.id);
        if (product) {
            res.status(200).json(product);
        } else {
            res.status(404).json({ error: 'Product not found' });
        }
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(400).json( { error: error.message });
    }
});

// Delete a Product By Id
router.delete('/:id', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const product = await Products.findByPk(req.params.id);
        if (product) {
            await product.destroy();
            res.status(204).send();
        } else {
            res.status(404).json( {error: 'Product Not Found.'});
        } 
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(400).json({ error: error.message });
    }
});

module.exports = router;


HTTP-400 comes from the server's side. Help us help you, and share the route's code.

HTTP 400 is "Bad Request"
That mean that the request is invalid. These errors are mostly client-side (where the data / request to be send is not in the right format).
Do you use any DTO / or input validation on server-side ?

@Mureinik Sure, I added the routes code.

@polozer my database is based on the models in my backend, would you want me to put them here?

When you get an HTTP-400 it's supposed to return an error (according to the route's code you shared) - { error: error.message }. Can you print it out and share with us?

The 400 you receive client-side seems to be send by your backend in the try/catch of your POST route. First of all, make sure you receive correctly the request in this route.
PS : Thats not the question, but would be better to construct the blob on "load" event and not "loadend", as "loadend" can be triggered even if file has not been read successfully

@Mureinik
it's the error:
"notNull Violation: Product.name cannot be null,
notNull Violation: Product.category cannot be null,
notNull Violation: Product.description cannot be null,
notNull Violation: Product.price cannot be null,
notNull Violation: Product.image cannot be null"
although I logged the values before sending them and they were right.

You are accessing http://localhost:3002/products/ route to create product.can you please explain how did it create product as per your defined route? In route file you va not defined any route that match to it.

I created the database models using sequelize in my backend, And there was allowNull attribute I did set it to false, and that was the reason of error, now I did solve that, now when I submit form my values don't send into database and it just creates an empty row, what should I do about this? as I said I logged values before sending and values were fine.

These are not mysql error messages. Check where you validate the input for your model and how the data is passed onto there.

I suspect req.body is not being parsed so you are passing an empty object to Products.create(req.body);. It looks like you are posting with a data structure using FormData() which send the data encoded as "multipart/form-data" so you need a parser on the server such as multer. Questions on how to do this have been asked on here about a million times.
